# Error: Access Denied in S3 bucket after applying VPC policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have applied a policy to [allow only connections from my VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html#example-bucket-policies-restrict-access-vpc):

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909153",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPC-only",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringNotEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-111bbb22"
         }
       },
       "Principal": "*"
     }
   ]
}
```

But now I'm getting "Access Denied" even when I try to access it from the AWS Console from an instance in the given VPC:

[image]

I've read https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-regain-access/, but unfortunately I use a company-provided federated login and I don't have access to the full root user.

My question is why can't I access the bucket even when inside the VPC?

Some similar questions that I found - [Policy Denying Access On Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307452/policy-denying-access-on-amazon-s3?rq=1) and [S3 VPC end point Bucket policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451435/s3-vpc-end-point-bucket-policy)

Comment: Install the awscli on that EC2 instance and then test S3 access using "aws s3 ls examplebucket".

Comment: I use a federated login (I login with my company's AD account). I don't have access to the root user or an IAM user. I am not sure if I have access to AWS CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent your policy from being applied to your federated users in AWS console, you could "whitelist" them using the [NotPrincipal](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#NotPrincipal) element instead of `Principal` in your policy statement. For example:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909153",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPC-only",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringNotEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-111bbb22"
         }
       },
       "NotPrincipal": {
         "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::YOUR-AWS-ACCOUNT-ID:saml-provider/YOUR-PROVIDER-NAME"
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a VPC endpoint for S3 set up?

There are two ways to access objects in S3.  One is through the AWS console and the other is through HTTPS calls to the S3 object.

If you're trying to access the bucket from the AWS console, then permission is governed by your IAM user/role and bucket policy.  You're using a federated login, so I'm assuming it's a role.

From an instance in VPC-111bbb222, log out of the AWS console and try to access an object in that bucket using the HTTPS URL.

Comment: Note that I'm using `aws:sourceVpc`, not `aws:sourceVpce` in the Policy. I'm following the tutorial "Restricting Access to a Specific VPC". The one for "Restricting Access to a Specific VPC Endpoint" is part above it.

Comment: Btw, I actually can access a file in the bucket from the VPC, but I can't administer the bucket (like adding other files, changing the policy etc.) I'm also trying to follow this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43372890/492336, but so far unsuccessfully.

Comment: If you can access an object in the bucket, then you might have an ACL that allows it.  Can you show us any ACLs in the Permissions tab?

Comment: I can't because I'm getting Access Denied once I apply the policy.

Comment: Ahhh, I'm following now!  I see that you're using aws:sourceVpc, but is a VPC endpoint in place?

1) If an endpoint is in place, any traffic destined for S3 from that VPC will be forced out of that endpoint.

2) The policy in place restricts any s3 actions that are not coming from the VPC.

3) If the source is being forced to be VPCE because of an endpoint presence, you'll never be able to get an instance within the VPC to administer the bucket properly because the policy will only allow a VPC source.  You would need to remove the endpoint to make your source VPC instead of VPCE.

Comment: I didn't quite follow that. Do you mean that my VPC might already have an Endpoint and this endpoint is not from the VPC? It's entirely possible because this VPC isn't administered just by me and I have no idea of all the configs there.

Comment: Let's find out if you have an endpoint (and route) in that VPC or not.  The AWS documentation says that aws:sourceVpc "is useful if you have multiple VPC endpoints configured..."  I'm assuming that sourceVpc and sourceVpce both expect traffic to come from a VPC endpoint.  If a VPC endpoint is NOT in use, then when you try to administer the bucket, you are coming from the internet.  Which would mean that you have locked yourself out of that bucket.  The root account or a support ticket can fix this for you.

Comment: Does the IAM role have necessary S3 permissions for the bucket? Using the bucket policy you are denying access but did you allow via the IAM permission policy of the IAM role you are using to sign-in? Also as @AppleBaggins said, please make sure the VPC has been configured properly. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html

Comment: His IAM role had enough permission to apply the policy, so I don't think IAM permissions are an issue.  He's just being denied access because (most likely) of the policy that was applied.